# symfony2.7 Liip\ImagineBundle failed to load class

Tags: php, symfony

When i want to create my custom post_procesor i have done what says [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/filters.html#post-processors) my custom post_procesor class is located here `src\xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer.php` and contents of if:

```
<?php
namespace xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer;
class TinifyPostProcessor implements PostProcessorInterface
{
....
}
```

my `app/service` :

```
services:
  app.post_processor.tinify_post_processor:
      class: xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer\TinifyPostProcessor
      tags:
          - { name: 'liip_imagine.filter.post_processor', post_processor: 'tinify_post_processor' }
```

but i got error `"Attempted to load class "TinifyPostProcessor" from namespace "Galmet\WebBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"` where i forgot `use`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class with fully qualified name:

```
xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer\TinifyPostProcessor
```

Should be in file:

```
src\xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer\TinifyPostProcessor.php
```

instead of

```
src\xyz\SomeBundle\Filter\ImageOptimizer.php
```